# React js Unable to get DesktopDatePicker value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, material-ui

I'm using `DesktopDatePicker` along with `useForm`.

```
 <Controller
  control={control}
  name="dob"
  render={({field}) => (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <DesktopDatePicker<Dayjs.Dayjs>
      label="For desktop"
      value={value}
      onChange={(newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      onError={(err) => {
        console.group('onError');
        console.log(err);
        console.groupEnd();
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
  )}
 />
```

On form submit the form data has `dob` as undefined. Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you are not using `field` inside `desktopdatepicker` hence its not working. please check https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-controller-5h1q5 on how to use Mui components with react hook form. you can solve issue by two methods.

**1) Basic method** : using `field` directly and removing `value` and `onChange`

```
 <Controller
   control={control}
   name="dob"
   render={({field}) => (
     <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
       <DesktopDatePicker
         {...field} 
         label="For desktop"
         onError={(err) => {
           console.group('onError');
           console.log(err);
           console.groupEnd();
         }}
         renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
       />
     </LocalizationProvider>
   )}
 />
```

**2) Advanced Method** : using `onChange`, `value` and `error`

```
const [popperState, setPopperState] = useState(false);

<Controller
  name="dob"
  control={control}
  render={({
    field: { onChange, value },
    fieldState: { error },
  }) => (
        <FormControl sx={{ custom css code here})}>
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DesktopDatePicker
              onOpen={() => setPopperState(true)}
              onClose={() => setPopperState(false)}
              onChange={popperState ? (() => undefined) : onChange}
              onAccept={(newValue) => {
                popperState ? onChange(newValue) : undefined;
              }}
              value={value}
              // inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
              // allowSameDateSelection
              // components={{
              //   OpenPickerIcon: CustomCalenderIcon,
              // }}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  error={!!error}
                  helperText={error?.message || ' '}
                  variant="outlined"
                  sx={{
                    custom css style here
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </FormControl>
      )}
    />
```